# Use neo4j Python driver transaction function non static

Tags: python, neo4j

The latest version of the official Python driver for neo4j suggests to use [transaction functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/sessions-transactions/#driver-transactions-transaction-functions) like so:

```
class Something:
    ...

    def add_person(self, name):
        with self._driver.session() as session:
            session.write_transaction(self.create_person_node, name)

    @staticmethod
    def create_person_node(tx, name):
        tx.run("CREATE (a:Person {name: $name})", name=name)
```

In all examples, the transaction functions are static. Is this necessary? Can they also access `self`?

```
class Something:
    ...

    def add_person(self, name):
        with self._driver.session() as session:
            session.write_transaction(self.create_person_node, name)

    def create_person_node(self, tx, name):
        tx.run("CREATE (a:Person {name: $name})", name=self.name)
```

Also, what is the advantage of transaction functions over `session.run()`?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not necessary for transaction functions to be static, they can refer to self. Just tested this by throwing some of my sandbox code into a class, using a non-static transaction function, it worked the same.

`write_transaction` adds an automatic-retry mechanism to handle some errors. This is mentioned in the [documentation for transaction functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/sessions-transactions/#driver-transactions-transaction-functions), in the paragraph directly below the sample code:

> Transaction functions are also able to handle connection problems and transient errors using an automatic retry mechanism. This retry capability can be configured on Driver construction.

There's more detailed documentation in [the API](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/1.6/transactions.html)

> Transaction functions are the most powerful form of transaction, providing **access mode override and retry capabilities**. These allow a function object representing the transactional unit of work to be passed as a parameter. This function is called one or more times, within a configurable time limit, until it succeeds. Results should be fully consumed within the function and only aggregate or status values should be returned. Returning a live result object would prevent the driver from correctly managing connections and would break retry guarantees.